Inequality involving the diagonal of a Hermitian matrix and a unitarily invariant norm
Assume E is a Hermitian matrix, does the following inequality always hold?
$\| \text{diag}(E) \|_w \leq \| E \|_w$
where
diag(E) denotes the diagonal matrix formed by the diagonal entries of
E, and $\|\cdot\|_w$ represents a unitarily invariant norm.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
